# Error while call prostresql procedure nestjs/typeorm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have this stored procedure to save a purchase with a token relate. But I'm facing an error when I try to call it in Nestjs/typeorm.

I checked and I'm passing the params except for the INOUT, because I just need the output.

Please, can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
create or replace procedure grab_token_and_create_purchase(
         stripeId VARCHAR,
          clientId INTEGER,
          purchaseData VARCHAR,
          price REAL,  
          productId INTEGER,
          INOUT client_purchase refcursor = 'client_purchase')
language plpgsql
as $$
declare

 product_company_name public.company.name%TYPE;
 product_token public.tag%ROWTYPE;
 purchase_id INTEGER;
 
begin

 SELECT name INTO product_company_name
 TARGET FROM public.company
    WHERE id = (SELECT company FROM public.ad WHERE id = productId );
 IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Product''s company not found %', productId;
 END IF;
 
 SELECT * INTO product_token
 FROM public.tokens
 WHERE product_id = productId
   AND taken = FALSE;
 IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'No more tokens avaliable %', productId;
 END IF;

    UPDATE public.tokens
    SET  taken = TRUE
    WHERE id = product_token;
  
    SELECT INTO purchase_id nextval('purchase_id_seq');
    
    INSERT INTO public.purchase (
      id
    , "stripeId"
    , "clientId"
    , "purchaseData"
    , price
    , "productId"
    , token
    , used
    , expired
    , active
    , refunded
    , "companyName"
    ) VALUES (
      purchase_id
    , stripeId
    , clientId
    , purchaseData
    , price
    , productId
    , product_token
    , FALSE
    , FALSE
    , TRUE
    , FALSE
    , product_company_name
    );
    
    SELECT   id
        , "stripeId"
        , "clientId"
        , "purchaseData"
        , price
        , "productId"
        , token
        , used
        , expired
        , active
        , refunded
        , "companyName"
    INTO client_purchase
    FROM public.purchase
    WHERE id = purchase_id;
   

end; $$
```

I call the procedure in a function using the @nestjs/typeorm. I'm using typescript.

```
 async grabTokenAndCreatePurchase(purchase: PurchaseInterface): Promise<Purchase> {
    try {
      const {clientId, stripeId, purchaseData, productId, price} = purchase;
      return await this.purchasesRepository.query(
        `grab_token_and_create_purchase @stripeid='${stripeId}', @clientId= ${clientId}, @purchaseData='${purchaseData}', @price=${price}, @productId=${productId}`);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error (
        `ERROR while saving the purchase - failed to call procedure. ${err}` );
    };
  }
```